# Best way to query a large list of nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I'm trying to do something like the following using the py2neo module to get information for a large quantity of nodes in a neo4j database that I already know the id's of:

```
query = f'''    
    MATCH 
        (n:MY_LABEL)
    OPTIONAL MATCH 
        (n) -- (u:OTHER_LABEL) // Won't always have a neighbor
    WHERE 
        id(n) in [{','.join(very_long_list_of_nids)}]
    RETURN 
        id(n) as nid, 
        n.feature1,
        u.feature2
'''
resp = graph.run(query)
```

And I have noticed it's far faster to just omit the `WHERE` clause, and do filtering after it returns the content of every `n:MY_LABEL` node. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

For reference, the `very_long_list_of_nodes` list is about 500k elements long (and I have tried batching it into smaller, 10k chunks and have the same problem) and the database contains 4m nodes, and 10m edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should:

1. Move the `WHERE` clause right under your `MATCH` clause. Currently, your `WHERE` clause is under the `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause, and so the ID filtering is only done after finding the relationships of **all** `MY_LABEL` nodes.
2. Remove the `:MY_LABEL` qualification from the `MATCH` clause. If you already get the node by native ID, checking the label is unnecessary; and you are not using indexing.
3. Pass the list of IDs as a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/). This will cause the Cypher query planner to run much faster (since the Cypher code will be simple), and once the plan is created it will be cached and reused every time you rerun the query with a new ID list. This also makes your client code simpler and faster as well.

This should be much faster:

```
query = f'''
    MATCH 
        (n)
    WHERE 
        ID(n) in $id_list
    OPTIONAL MATCH 
        (n) -- (u:OTHER_LABEL) // Won't always have a neighbor
    RETURN 
        ID(n) as nid, 
        n.feature1,
        u.feature2
'''
resp = graph.run(query, id_list=very_long_list_of_nids)
```

Also, if the relationships between `MY_LABEL` and `OTHER_LABEL` always flow in one direction, you should consider using a directional relationship pattern (either `-->` or `<--`) in your `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause, especially if your `MY_LABEL` nodes have other kinds of relationships that flow in the opposite direction.